# Change permanently boost.txt

Tags: linux, arch-linux, cpufreq

Whenever I change the

`sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost.txt`

file, when I restart the computer, it goes back to its original state. How i permanently change this value to 0 ?

I added a one shot systemctl service and fix that way

Comment: So what you actually want is disable CPU boosting entirely, right? [Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177011)'s a discussion thread from Arch community. According to one commenter "one possible solution is to use a systemd "oneshot"-type service file".

Comment: its work thx for help

Comment: Thx for letting  me know. I put that in as an answer, could you please accept it so this question doesn't stay as another ghost in the Unanswered -queue? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177011) discussion in Arch Linux community this can be arranged by making an "oneshot" -type service file.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Intel CPU boost completely,
you could use the
[wrmsr command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/wrmsr.1.html)
with the "all" parameter:

```
wrmsr -a 0x1a0 0x4000850089
```

To re-enable turbo boost:

```
sudo wrmsr -a 0x1a0 0x850089
```

If this also doesn't survive the boot, try the script in
[disable_intel_turbo_boost](https://gist.github.com/lucasbrigida/1761084e0d96bacefc76461223b5a0b9).

Comment: Note: This is entirely untested - I don't have a Linux computer here to test on.